Соединение таблиц без использования inner join, как оно работает?
Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает такое соединение таблиц в запросе вместо join? Просто перечисляются таблицы. Далее в бизнес-логике к этому запросу, к блоку where могут присоединяться еще условия с and и or, поэтому, как мне сказали, здесь не подходит использование join и надо соединять таблицы именно так. Почему? Я первый раз вижу такое соединение таблиц без джойнов.
SELECT SUM(`order`.total )  as count
FROM `check`, `order`, `posinfo`
WHERE `check`.id = `order`.order_check_id
    AND `order`.canseled=false



Ну это как раз старая запись сцепки таблиц, когда условия связывания прописываются в конструкции where. Так можно делать. А вот тот, кто сказал, что join не подходит, наверное книжку по SQL не дочитал :)

"мне сказали, здесь не подходит использование join и надо соединять таблицы именно так. Почему?" --- разве не логично спросить это именно того человека, кто это сказал?

Странно, что нет никакого условия на таблицу posinfo.  А так то ну это типичный JOIN по сценарию - две таблицы соединяются по id.

А что такое canseled?  Это can selled или cancelled?

Это устаревшая запись, эквивалентная нынешнему CROSS JOIN
SELECT * FROM a,b <=> SELECT * FROM a CROSS JOIN b
При этом SELECT * FROM a CROSS JOIN b WHERE a.id = b.id семантически эквивалентно SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
Соответственно SELECT * FROM a,b WHERE a.id = b.id даст тот же результат, что и SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
Для внутреннего соединения на самом деле не важно где условие, в ON или в WHERE, разница есть только для внешний (LEFT, RIGHT и FULL JOIN)

Всё так, но при этом JOIN ... ON ... визуально лучше воспринимается - сразу видно, по каким полям идёт соединение таблиц, не нужно вылавливать это соединение где-то в WHERE среди других условий выборки. Собственно, поэтому без JOIN и устаревшая форма записи.
